# jQuery clone wrap and prependTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, prepend

```
var orgin = $( ".images > a" ).clone();
$(orgin).prependTo( ".images .thumbnails .slideshow").wrap('<li></li>');
```

I have tried different methods, but I am trying to clone an element and then wrap it with `<li>` tags and then prepend it to `.slideshow`

If I remove `.wrap('<li></li>')` from the code above, the content is cloned to where I want it but it with the missing code, it doesn't wrap with what I need.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/mGKJ2/1/

Comment: could you please attach HTML src

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping the cloned element before you append it:

```
$(orgin).wrap('<li></li>').parent().prependTo( ".images .thumbnails .slideshow");
```

Note the `parent()` is required as the `wrap` returns the inner element, and you need to append the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(orgin).wrap('<li></li>').parent().prependTo( ".images .thumbnails .slideshow");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UNyeQ/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
$('<li>'+orgin+'</li>').prependTo( ".images .thumbnails .slideshow");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 $('.images .thumbnails .slideshow').prepend('<li>'+$('.images > a').clone()+'</li>')
```